# Perl RegExp: Delete part of the string when a specific string is present

Tags: regex, perl

How to apply Perl RegExp to delete the first part of the string **if** the string includes either `Potatoes` or `Peaches`?

If possible, do not use the if/else condition but only the RegExp.

```
Input:
Apples Peaches Grapes 
Spinach Tomatoes Carrots
Corn Potatoes Rice

Output:
Peaches Grapes 
Spinach Tomatoes Carrots 
Potatoes Rice
```

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

$string1 = "Apples Peaches Grapes ";
$string2 = "Spinach Tomatoes Carrots";
$string3 = "Corn Potatoes Rice";

#Use RegExp to output strings with first word deleted  
#if it includes either Peaches or Rice.

$string1 =~ s///;
$string2 =~ s///;
$string2 =~ s///;


say $string1;
say $string2;
say $string3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following expression:

```
^(?=.*\bPeaches\b|.*\bPotatoes\b)\S+\s
```

- `^` Beginning of string.
- `(?=.*\bPeaches\b|.*\bPotatoes\b)` Positive lookahead, ensures that `Peaches` or `Potatoes` substring are present in the string.
- `\S+\s` Matches any non whitespace characters followed by whitespace.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yhqyIo/1).

---

**Perl** demo:

```
use feature qw(say);

$string1 = "Apples Peaches Grapes";
$string2 = "Spinach Tomatoes Carrots";
$string3 = "Corn Potatoes Rice";

$string1 =~ s/^(?=.*\bPeaches\b|.*\bPotatoes\b)\S+\s//;
$string2 =~ s/^(?=.*\bPeaches\b|.*\bPotatoes\b)\S+\s//;
$string2 =~ s/^(?=.*\bPeaches\b|.*\bPotatoes\b)\S+\s//;


say $string1;
say $string2;
say $string3;
```

Prints:

```
Peaches Grapes
Spinach Tomatoes Carrots
Corn Potatoes Rice
```